# I want to assign javascript variable to html element inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert javascript variable value in html element inside javascript.. But it's not working properly.. following are my code..

```
 window.onload = function() {
    var image=document.getElementById('img').value;
        var img = '<div id="pic"><img src="image" width="200" height="108" /><p></p></div>';
      }
```

This is the function. Here i'm getting image in variable image.. i'm trying to assign this image to in one div id pic.. there i'm assigning src="image" which i got in var image.. But its not working..

Answer (score 4):

You need to insert the value into the string:

```
var img = '<div id="pic"><img src="' + image + '" width="200" height="108" /><p></p></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
 var img = '<div id="pic"><img src="'+image+'" width="200" height="108" /><p></p></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this instead:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var image=document.getElementById('img').value;
    document.getElementById('pic').innerHTML='<img src="'+image+'" width="200" height="108" /><p></p>';
}
```